# reset variables when pass to an another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue

my problem is that when i switch to an another ViewController, my variables of the previous VC call are reset so i can't do what i want after

```
@IBAction func BackBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    self.nbrQst = 10
    self.Switch1A = 2
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Numero", sender: self)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Numero" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
        vc.nbrQt = nbrQst
    }
    if segue.identifier == "Numero" {
        let vcNv = segue.destination as! ViewController
        vcNv.Switch1 = Switch1A
    }
}
```

below the way that i send information from my Lvl1 file to the lvl selector file to add a if else for unblocks the lvl

```
@IBAction func BackBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    self.nbrQst = 10
    self.Switch1A = 2
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Numero", sender: self)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
    vc.nbrQt = nbrQst
    vc.Switch1 += 2
}
```

that's the second ViewController who send the number to the first one, and i want that the first one remember the number and add them up each time I press the button that sends the numbers

Comment: Completely unrelated but this is not Windows 95 where variable/file names have been restricted to max. 8 characters 

Comment: I started code men week ago so i'm not an expert

Comment: There's a lot of confusion here, but don't worry, I sort of get the feeling that it's not a hard question, I'll help you solve it. But could you rephrase your question? I'm having a hard time trying to understand it. What exactly is it that you want to do?

Comment: @K.Wu first, thanks you, i'm french so sorry for my english. I'm making a quiz and I have 5 ViewController, 1 for the level selector and the 4 other for each lvl (the question)  my problem is that i want to pass variables from the lvl VC to the lvl Selector VC and when i do that the variables in the lvl selector VC are reset and that prevents me from checking if the level has already been played for definitively unblocks it

Comment: If you'd like to add the numbers, you need a code that adds the numbers. In your code you only have assignments (which simply transfer/overwrite the value from one to another).

Comment: If you explain it visually and give better meaningful names for the variables, I'm sure people would understand better and be ready to help.

Comment: @battlmonstr how i can add numbers ? i will try to give you more code

Comment: Ok, I sort of understand. So, initially, you're in lvl selector VC, when you select a lvl, let's say lvl 2, you then go to lvl 2 VC and answer the question there. When you submit your answer, you'll navigate back to lvl selector VC, AND, if the answer is correct, you want to add the total points to lvl selector VC. Correct?

Comment: @K.Wu no, i go back to lvl selector when the 10 Question of the lvl are finish for go to the next lvl and my problem is that i want to definitly unblocks the lvl so i want to add numbers to a variables in the Lvl selector file each time i push a lvl button in the lvl selector

Comment: @Bobob OK, user selects a lvl in selector VC, answers 10 questions there and com back to selector, where they can choose the next lvl. Repeat until all levels are completed. Every time the user answers a question correctly, you want to update the points in selector VC.

Comment: @K.Wu yes but not for the point just for unblocks definitly the lvl, if not, when a user finish the 4 lvl and want to remake the Second for example, the 4th will be block because in my code if i finish the second lvl, it unblocks the third and the oser after will be always blocks

Answer (score 0):

Let's call "Selector VC" the main VC.

The reason why those numbers reset in main VC is that when you press the "BackBtn", you're not actually going back to main VC, you're creating a new main VC and going there (because you did `performSegue(withIdentifier: "Numero", sender: self)` in `BackBtn` function, `performSegue` always takes you to a new VC rather than taking you back). The new main VC has all those fields starting from an initial number (I assume initially they're zero).

What you want to do is to go BACK, not forward. Depending on how you went to the level VC from main VC, you have different ways of going back to main VC.

**If you're pushing everything onto a navigation controller, then you can go back by:**

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

**If you're presenting everything modally, you can go back by**

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You said, you want to update the value in main VC so that you can block/unblock next level. A very standard way to achieve this is via `delegate`, please Google this ("delegates in Swift") and follow their tutorials there.

I strongly recommend that you take an online course on swift development before you go ahead and develop your own app, because you could potentially do a lot of things wrong and waste a lot of your time trying to get an answer from Stack Overflow.

Comment: i'm going to check this, thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: i try  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) but when i call it, it return instant in the lvl VC

Comment: @Bobob Your question is not hard at all, I know what's going on but I cannot answer it, because it requires a lot of explanations. e.g., segues, navigation controllers, delegates, closures (completion handlers) and perhaps some high level designs. You should take an online course first, I'd recommend going to a website called "Udemy" and search for a swift development course. After that, this problem will be a piece of cake. Again, you can't just try to develop a small app without taking a course first.